# How to align the content center in middle of a line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align 3 button in middle of a line. Using CSS and HTML to achieve the result

What I have done:

1/ Css :

```
.strike {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.strike > span {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 9999px;
    height: 1px;
    background: white;
}

.strike > span:before {
    right: 100%;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.strike > span:after {
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

2/ html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 ">
        <div class="strike">
            <span>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-just-icon"
                    style="background-color: #1da1f2">
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-just-icon"
                    style="background-color: #3B5998">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-just-icon"
                    style="background-color: #0084ff">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The result: 3 buttons are in middle of line but they are not aligned.

[image]

What I expected:

3 buttons are align vertical center with the line.

Any suggestion is appreciated

**** EDIT *****

I will update the result from suggestions here

1/ From @Gerard

[image]

Comment: try with padding

Comment: there are many do this... Flexbox, padding, line-height... But it'll be easier to help you with snippet code.. For me, flexbox is the easier way to do this

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) because it is responsive by nature.

```css
.strike {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: thin solid red; /* for visibility only */
}

.strike:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1px;
  background: gray;
  z-index: -1;
}

.strike>button {
  min-width: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.btn.tw {
  background-color: #1da1f2
}

.btn.fb {
  background-color: #3B5998
}

.btn.ms {
  background-color: #0084ff
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 ">
    <div class="strike">
      <button class="btn tw">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn fb">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </button>
      <button class="btn ms">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Gerard, but still no luck. :((

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
.strike > span{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

with snippet code it was be easier to help you but try with this code...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your snippet, I just simply replaced my code with the snippet, but it doesn't work. I may miss something ?

Comment: do you have an online preview? or a snippet code to show us the result? because like this it'll be difficult to help you without the rest of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `vertical-align: middle;`

```
.strike > span button {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it still doesn't affect the result.

Comment: use `!important` after middle

Comment: I am happy to share code online, just don't know how? Sorry I am quite fresh to html and css, just playing with it for a while.

Comment: @PeterPham My code is working in my side, BY THE WAY, I check other answers and gerard answer also work that I vote to that

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear of what you are asking though. But is this what you need?

```css
.strike {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.strike>span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.strike>span:before,
.strike>span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
}

.strike>span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.strike>span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

button {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 22px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 ">
    <br/>
    <div class="strike">
      <span>
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-just-icon"
                    style="background-color: #1da1f2">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-just-icon"
                    style="background-color: #0084ff">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-messenger" style="color: white;"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-just-icon"
                    style="background-color: #3B5998">
                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-f" style="color: white;"></i>
                </button>
            </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```